# PHP shows top 4 rows on different places

Tags: php, html, mysql

**I have the following html code:**

```
<div class="content-block1">
    <div class="image-block1"></div>
    <div class="bear1"></div>
    <div class="where-block1"></div>
    <div class="intro-block1"></div>
    <div class="map-block1"></div>
    <div class="extra-block1"></div>
    <div class="coordinates-block1"></div>
    <a href=""><div class="button-block1">More...</div></a>
</div>

<div class="content-block2">
    <div class="image-block2"></div>
    <div class="bear2">/div>
    <div class="where-block2"></div>
    <div class="intro-block2"></div>
    <div class="map-block2"></div>
    <div class="extra-block2"></div>
    <div class="coordinates-block2"></div>
    <a href=""><div class="button-block2">More...</div></a>
</div>
```

**..and the following PHP code:**

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$database = "db";

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = mysql_query("select image,where,intro,map,extra,coordinates from content limit 2");

mysql_close();
```

Now, I've tried so hard to do following: I need to select top 2 rows in table content which include columns image,where,intro,map,extra and coordinates (bear excluded). Okay, I've selected them with query, BUT I have next problem -> I need to put content from first row in first DIV element called content-block1, so, columns image,where,intro,map,extra and coordinates need to fit in their divs in content-block1.

Also, I need to put data from second row (image,where,intro,map,extra and coordinates) into DIV element called content-block2 into DIVs where they belong. Can you help me please?

Comment: Read, mark, learn, and inwardly digest the attached https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this could be what you are looking for...

```
$host = "localhost";
$user = "username";
$pass = "password";
$database = "db";

mysql_connect($host,$user,$pass,$database) or die(mysql_error());
mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");

$query = mysql_query("select image,where,intro,map,extra,coordinates from content limit 2");

$i = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($query , MYSQL_ASSOC))
{ 
    $i++;
    echo '
        <div class="content-block{$i}">
            <div class="image-block{$i}">{$row['yourvaluehere']}</div>
            <div class="bear{$i}">{$row['yourvaluehere']}</div>
            <div class="where-block{$i}">{$row['yourvaluehere']}</div>
            <div class="intro-block{$i}">{$row['yourvaluehere']}</div>
            <div class="map-block{$i}">{$row['yourvaluehere']}</div>
            <div class="extra-block{$i}"></div>
            <div class="coordinates-block{$i}">{$row['yourvaluehere']}</div>
            <a href=""><div class="button-block{$i}">More...</div></a>
        </div>
     ';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your Query to this

```
$query = mysql_query("select * from content limit 0, 2");
```

Source = https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/select.html

Then do the following to get your query values

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query))
  {
$image = $row['image'];
$where = $row['where'];
$map = $row['intro'];
$extra = $row['extra'];
$coordinates = $row['coordinates'];

}
```

This would be your query if you were selecting the top two only

```
$query = mysql_query("select TOP 2 * from content");
```

Comment: I've probably mistyped heading of this question. I need to select top 2 rows in MySQL :)

Comment: Ah okay give me a second @ronniejespersens answer above is very good for the html part let me just give you the query to select the first two now.

Comment: I've found solution with your part of code and par which Ronnie Jespersen wrote...I've added variables initialization inside while loop from Roonie and it works! Thank you both! :)